# Convert a column (in Panda's DataFrame) from hexadecimal to int, skip lines with Nan or None, for large data sets> 10GB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, hex

I have a recording of a Can-Bus transmission and I want to analyze it now. In the past, I used Excel for it. But now I am faced with huge amounts of data (> 10GB). With "pd.read_csv" I can load the data wonderfully into a data frame. But the hexadecimal numbers are called a string in the following form "6E" and not "0x6E". Furthermore, some columns are filled with "None".

In the second paragraph I pointed out that I tested it with a for loop and an if query on None, this works, but this procedure takes a very long time

```py
    def load_data(self, file_folder, file_type):

        df_local_list = []

        # Load-Filenames as string in list "all_files"
        full_path = glob.glob(file_folder + "/*." + file_type)
        self.all_files = natsort.natsorted(full_path)

        # Walk through all files and load the content in list "self.df"
        for file in self.all_files:

            # Read file-content to data-frame-variable "self.df"
            local_df = pd.read_csv(file, names=self.header_list,
                                   delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=12, skipfooter=3, header=13,
                                   error_bad_lines=False, engine='python')

            # Save the file-content without the last two lines --> End-Header
            # self.df_list.append(local_df[:-2])
            df_local_list.append(local_df)

        self.df = pd.concat(df_local_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

        self.df['Byte0_int'] = ('0x' + self.df['Byte0']).apply(int, base=0)
```

I would like to have a fast function which converts selected columns from hex to int, skipping the "None" values.

Comment: I suppose with converting "to int" you mean to a decimal representation containing only integers?

Comment: `if var is not None:`?

Comment: In the second paragraph I pointed out that I tested it with a for loop and an if query on None, this works, but this procedure takes a very long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I did this :

```py
self.df['Byte0_int'] = self.df['Byte0_int'].dropna().map(lambda x:int(x, 16))
```

In short, I remove `NaN` first, then I convert everything else from hex to int

No need to prefix "**0x**" since they are processed the same:

```
>>> int("0x5e",16)
94
>>> int("5e",16)
94
```

I suggest to profile the timings of your code because the concat could be costly. You also could have a look at `dask` to process many files